# JSON.stringify and number as string

Tags: javascript, json

Is there a simple way to deal with this example situation

```
var data = {
     "phone":  input
}
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
```

In the situation where the payload is used in an API call and the API demands that phone value is a string, however, phone numbers can just be entered as numbers  or strings e.g.  123777777 or 1237-77777 etc

I tried adding quotes, but JSON.stringify escape them so the end up being part of the final data.

The 'hack' solution I found was to add a trailing space i.e.

```
var data = {
     "phone":  input + " "
}
```

But want to know if there is a simple and neat way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: So... you don't want the dashes?

Comment: No I want it to be treated as a string, thanks

Answer (score 9):

Strings don't have to have anything in them, so you *could* do:

```
var data = {
    "phone": input + ""
};
```

or `"" + input` would work as well. But in this situation I usually use the `String` function:

```
var data = {
    "phone": String(input)
};
```

**Note:** Not `new String(...)`, just `String(...)`.

There's nothing wrong with the `input.toString()` option others have suggested either, provided you know that `input` will be something other than `null` or `undefined`. (If it were `null` or `undefined`, it would cause an error.)

Comment: Thanks, looks like what I should use

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sure it's a string call `toString()` which ensures numbers are parsed as strings.

```
var data = {
  "phone":  input.toString()
}
```

Best thing is, that even if you have a string this won't throw an error. It will always be a string. See here for more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Answer (score 1):

Can always use `toString()`. This will work even if it is a string

```
var data = {
     "phone":  input.toString()
}
```

Comment: Well, not *always* because things like null or undefined don't have that method, but it'll work if input is guaranteed to be a string or a number.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
var input=1234567890;
var data = {
     "phone":  input.toString()
}
console.log("inputType---->"+$.type(input));
var payload = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log("payload----afterstringify--->"+payload);
console.log("dataType------->"+$.type(data.phone));
console.log("payloadType-------->"+$.type(payload));

});
```